# Tab showing on homepage which shouldnt show

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is my base.html file:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/css/bootstrap-theme.css' %}">
</head>
</html>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default"></nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/fitbit/">Fitbit</a></li>
            {% if user.is_anonymous %}
            {% else %}
            <li><a href="/logout/">Log Out</a></li>
            {% endif %}      
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
<center>

{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</center> 

<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="css/js/jquery.min.js"> <\/script>')</script>
<script src="/static/css/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/css/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
<footer>
<p>&copy; 2016 Hanze Hogeschool Groningen</p>
</footer>
```

As you can see I'm doing a check if the user is anonymous if he is not anonymous it should show the log out button. But at the moment when I return to the homepage it still shows the Log Out button.

My question is, how do I make it so that the log out will not show on the homepage. According to my own thinking I think django still thinks I'm not anonymous on the homepage.

And this is the image for the problem:
[homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J34SS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using [`is_authenticated`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_authenticated) instead:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <li><a href="/logout/">Log Out</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

And, you are not passing the request context from your view to a template, use [`render()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/http/shortcuts/#render):

```
return render(request, 'index.html')
```

Comment: But then if I log in this happens: [link](http://puu.sh/o21qn/6d8bbed5ab.png)[/link]

Comment: @Ruska_JAB could you also show the code of your view? Thanks.

Comment: `from django.contrib.auth import logout
    from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

def main_page(request):
    return render_to_response('index.html')

def logout_page(request):
    """
    Log users out and re-direct them to the main page.
    """
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')`  @alexce There is no login def because we use the auth.views.

Comment: @Ruska_JAB okay, it looks like the actual `user` is not in the context of a template. Please show your `INSTALLED_APPS` and template related settings.

Comment: `INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'portal.apps.PortalConfig',
    'fitbitoauth2.apps.Fitbitoauth2Config',
    'bootstrap3',
]`

Comment: `TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]`

Comment: @Ruska_JAB okay, updated the answer, please check if it helps.